# How can i back in a specific tab

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, postback

I have a problem when I use bootstrap tab in asp.net. If I have a button with any action in the tab 2 or 3 the postback always returns in tab 1.

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-left" id="tabs1">
            <li class="active"><a aria-expanded="true" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Produtos</a></li>
            <li><a aria-expanded="false" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Detalhes</a></li>
            <li><a aria-expanded="false" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Pagamento</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content mb-lg" id="tabs1c">
        <div class="tab-pane clearfix active" id="tab1">
            Test page 1
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            Test page 2
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" onclick="teste_click" Text="Test" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not using a tabstrip ? And can you give any button action C# code ?

Comment: I'm using a tamplate purchased by my customer. I'm not sure if I know how can I use tabstrip. Yes I can, but after the postback always return in the tab 1.

Comment: you might be looking for **ajax posting**

Comment: Why PostBack ? Are you performing any server side computation ? If performing then enclose your server control within UpdatePanel, Doing so will performing postback but prevents u from rebuilding of page again.